# How to use Google Fusion Tables

Tags: google-maps, google-fusion-tables

Am beginner to Fusion tables Concept. I have already tried my hands on some basic features of Fusion tables SQL API and liked it. Following are some questions I have with respect to the same. Request your help in the same.

1. Whats the benefit of using Fusion table API for storing data and presenting it on Map via  Google Maps V3 API which could other wise be done using V3 API over our own data source?
2. Whats the way forward on Private Fusion tables? I am worried on removing the technology altogether since its still in Beta or putting usage limitations that would limit the usage of the end application? Also can the data security be trusted.
3. Whats the difference between Table API and SQL API?

Answer (score 0):

I can only answer question 1. I can think of several advantages which will depend on the nature of your data.

- Greatly improved map display performance when dealing with thousands of markers (points, lines and polygons). Tiles are generated dynamically by Google for quick display via the Map API with no marker creation overhead
- Geocoding. Addresses and/or existing KML can be used when you lack lat/lon locations
- There is a fairly simple SQL like filtering mechanism via the Maps API which includes spatial queries
- FT have an undocumented but extremely useful JSONP option which uses the same SQL like syntax.

Comment: Thanks Eric. Hopefully someone clarifies on the point-2 so that i can design my solution.

Comment: Those non-technical questions would be appropriate in the [Fusion-Tables API Users Group](http://groups.google.com/group/fusion-tables-users-group?hl=en&pli=1)